# Can a ValueSelector filter on one ValueRangeProvider?

Tags: optaplanner

I have a chained variable with multiple value ranges (anchors and chained entities).

```
private CarAvailability carAvailability = null
  @PlanningVariable(
    graphType = PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED,
    valueRangeProviderRefs = Array("cars", "rides"))
```

Is there an option on value selectors to use a specific value range only? Like this for example:

```
<valueSelector variableName="carAvailability" valueRangeProvider="cars"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not currently. It's a potential RFE, create a jira for it?